# Why is html5 boilerplate image replacement not working here?

Tags: css, html5boilerplate, image-replacement

http://jsfiddle.net/hydroplane/r4Kn6/

I need to move that 'reblog' text out of the screen. Does anybody know why the h5bp .ir class isn't working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace in css this

```
.my-like:hover{ background-position: 0 50%;
```

with

```
.my-like:hover{ background-position: 0 50%; }
```

because you have not closet .my-like:hover

You can see it here  http://jsfiddle.net/r4Kn6/3/